# Forced fixed-size iFrame in iPhone web app?

Tags: php, iphone, html, iframe, web-applications

I have a iFrame whose content changes sizes. I want my iframe to stay the same size all the time. My code looks like this:

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="home.php" width="320" height="360"></iframe>
```

And for some reason, on my iPhone when links are clicked and the content changes sizes, so does the iFrame. It works fine on my computer browser. I specifically put in width and heights, but apparently I didn't listen...

What's up with that? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to put inline style in there to overwrite it?

```
<iframe id="frame1" src="home.php" width="320" height="360" style="width:320px;height:360px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: can you give me a link to see your problem in action?